# Use regex to substitute a match except the first and last characters

Tags: regular-expression, search-replace

Maybe the title isn't to explicative; feel free to improve it.

I have the text below:

```
1. Intro          |timetracking-intro|$
2. Uso            |timetracking-usage|$
3. Comandi        |timetracking-commands|$
```

I want to replace all space between the title and the tag with dots, but the first and the last, like this:

```
1. Intro ........ |timetracking-intro|$
2. Uso .......... |timetracking-usage|$
3. Comandi ...... |timetracking-commands|$
```

After an hour of attempts without success I can't understand this:

1. `:s/\A\s\A/./gc`
   This match also the firts space after the word "intro". Why? I used \A to not match the first space! (in the picture I grouped, `\(\A\s\A\)` but is the same).
   [image]
2. `:s/\(\A\zs\s\ze\A\)/./gc`
   but this regex match only alternate spaces, and match also the last space!!
   [image]

I had also some more funny results... :-/

Can anyone explain me why and how to do what I want?

Comment: `\A` means non-alphabetic character (`:help \A`).

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose you:

```
:s/\s\@<=\s\s\@=/./g
```

Where:

- `\s\@<=` match only if the previous character is a space
- `\s\@=` match only if the next character is a space

Since both match with zero width you don't have the one out of two effect.

Comment: All the answers works, but this is the more elegant and compact.  

I didn't understand the zero-width matches with `\@=`,  `\@!`, etc . 
Could you show me some link to read for a better explanation than the pattern.txt?

Comment: Excuse me @Vivian, I'm thinking about this solution and my second try. Except for the mistake at the end (\A match the `|`) tell me if I understand: I see highlighted alternated spaces because the match include three characters, and then the next match start after the previous? For this reason you use `\@=`? In effect my "2." corrected with the "\@"works: `:s/\(\A\@<=\zs\s\ze\s\@=\)/./gc`. The \zs and \ze in this case is redundant, and simplifying this I reach the compactness of your answer.  The clue is `\@=` and `\@<=`, right?

Comment: @Antonio, you are right :-) I have made other tests and the culprit seems to be `\zs`: `\s\zs` match with zero with but consume one character (a space). It seems that `\s\@<=\s\ze\s` is also a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:%s/  \+/\=' '.repeat('.',len(submatch(0))-2).' '/g
```

`%s/PATTERN/\=EXPR/g` substitutes all occurrences of `PATTERN` with the result from evaluating `EXPR`

`\+` matches at least 2 spaces

`len(submatch(0))` is the length of the currently matched text

`repeat('.',len(submatch(0))-2)` creates the sequence of dots

`' '.` `.' '` surrounds it with spaces

Comment: This answer would be improved by explanation

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way, but this is what I came up with:

`:s/\S\s\zs\s*\ze\s\S/\=substitute(submatch(0), '\s', '.', 'g')/`

`\A` matches anything that isn't an alphabetic character, so it makes sense that it matches a space.  Instead, you'd want to use `\S` to find the boundaries of the spaces.

The pattern part can be explained as: "Find a non-space followed by a space.  Then find 0 or more spaces, which will be the part we operate on in the replacement part.  Then find another space followed by a non-space".

The replacement part then uses `\=substitute()` to then do a find/replace on the spaces found between the `\zs` and `\ze`.  I'm not sure if there's another way to dynamically do a replacement when there's a variable number of characters in the captured match.

Comment: Since you already limit the match with zs/ze, and it can only be spaces, you probably want `repeat('.', len(submatch(0)))` or possibly a use of `tr()`